# Iterator Implementation

Tags: java, iterator

I had to write my own iterator implementation for my structure which has `ArrayList<Vector>` field. An iterator is supposed to iterate over mentioned `List`. Any suggestions on improving it, or anything else?

```
public class ExamplesIterator implements Iterator<Vector> {

    private List<Vector> examples;  //ArrayList<Vector> will be set here
    private int          index;

    public ExamplesIterator(List<Vector> examples) {
        this.examples = examples;
        index = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Vector next() {
        if(hasNext()) {
            return examples.get(index++);
        } else {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("There are no elements size = " + examples.size());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return !(examples.size() == index);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        if(index <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("You can't delete element before first next() method call");
        }
        examples.remove(--index);
    }
}
```

Comment: In Java it is illegal to call `remove()` twice in a row, or without calling `next()` first. See this code I have written here for some ideas: https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/blob/master/core/src/java/org/jdom2/ContentList.java#L655

Comment: @rolfl I will take this into account. Thanks. :)

Comment: this article may help you: http://www.yegor256.com/2015/04/30/iterating-adapter.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your implementation is overall very good, two small comments:

- Improving readability for return statement in `hasNext` to `return examples.size() != index;`
- Making the `examples` field **final**: `private final List<Vector> examples;`

However, if the `Vector` class here is [java.util.Vector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) you should know that it is considered deprecated in favor of the `ArrayList` class.

Also, since you create your iterator from a `List<Vector>` you could get an `Iterator<Vector>` by calling `list.iterator();`

Comment: Well... I completely forgot about that I can call  `list.iterator();` :P. Thank you !